# Batch script looping during FTP transfer

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, ftp, cmd

I'm working on a batch script that takes converted video files and emails them to a user. However, after the conversion is complete and the script begins uploading them to a server, the batch script is started again. This issue is causing the files to be converted and uploaded multiple times, it is also sending duplicate emails to the same user. What could be causing this script to restart?

**Note:** When I say "started again" or "restart", I mean that a new instance of the script is started before the other has completed.

**EDIT:** This script has been updated due to formatting issues as recommended below, however the problem still persists.

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mpg -qscale 0 -y C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mp4
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mpg -q:v 6 -y C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.ogv
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mpg -q:v 9 -y C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.webm
(
echo option batch abort
echo option confirm off
echo open ftp://example.org:example@example/
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mp4 /domains/example.org/html/wfsb/video/
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.ogv /domains/example.org/html/wfsb/video/
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.webm /domains/example.org/html/wfsb/video/
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.txt /domains/example.org/html/wfsb/video/
echo exit
) > ftpScript%1.txt
C:\winscp.com /script=ftpScript%1.txt
del C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mpg
del C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mp4
del C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.ogv
del C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.webm
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f send.php %1
```

And the script starts a new instance on this line:

```
 C:\winscp.com /script=ftpScript%1.txt
```

I've looked at similar questions, and it looks like many are related to the batch script file name being identical to a command in the script. In example 'FTP.bat' when there is an FTP command in the file. I do not believe this is the issue because the filename is 'ftp_script.bat'.

Please let me know if I can provide any other information to help clarify this issue.

Comment: You pass the recording number as %1, so are you trying to FTP multiple streams at one time? If so, your `del ftpScript*.txt` may be deleting the control file of another transfer which may be upsetting WINSCP, maybe?

Comment: %1 is the time and date of recording. '%1.mpg' would turn into something like: '14-04-17-15-47.mpg'. Any previous control files are deleted before the new one is created. I'm not understanding why WINCSP would be confused. Could you explain that to me in a little more detail? Thank you!

Comment: You create `ftp_result.txt` with WINSCP.COM then overwrite it twice...why?

Comment: It was just a thought... your WINSCP may be busy FTPing 14-04-17-15-47.mpg with a control file called `ftpScript14-04-17-15-47` and then you start another FTP and you delete ftpScript* which the first WINSCP was still using.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this could possibly be causing this issue! I didn't realize that the WINCSP command was being included in the control file. How is WINCSP creating ftp_result.txt twice? Perhaps I should remove "> ftp_result.txt" on the WINCSP line.

Comment: The WINSCP command does some FTP transfers and writes its results into `ftp_result.txt`, but on the next line you do `echo %1 > ftp_result.txt` which will overwrite the results from WINSCP, then on the next line, you overwrite it again.

Comment: Mark, I now understand! Thank you for pointing this out. I have a feeling that this will resolve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually an answer, but formatting is hard to read in Comments, so I am suggesting something to clarify/simplify your script...

You might find this easier:

```
(
echo option batch abort
echo option confirm off
echo open ftp://example.org:example@example.com/
echo lcd C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi
echo cd /domains/example.org/html/video
echo put %1.mp4
echo put %1.ogv
echo put %1.webm
echo put %1.txt
echo exit
) > ftpScript%1.txt
```

in place of this:

```
del ftpScript*.txt
echo option batch abort> ftpScript%1.txt
echo option confirm off>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo open ftp://example.org:example@example.com/>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.mp4 /domains/example.org/html/video/>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.ogv /domains/example.org/html/video/>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.webm /domains/example.org/html/video/>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo put C:\projects\weatherRecorder\avi\%1.txt /domains/example.org/html/video/>> ftpScript%1.txt
echo exit>> ftpScript%1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up this script Mark! Just so I understand, what is the purpose of parenthesis in the modified script? I appreciate your help.

Comment: It just puts all the outputs of all the `echo` commands together and writes them into file `ftpScript%1.txt`. Essentially it makes them one sub-command.

Comment: Mark, this makes a lot more sense! Thank you. I will test this version this afternoon, I will remember to mark as correct if it resolves the issue!

Comment: Hello Mark, unfortunately the looping continues even with the modified script. I'm wondering if the application has a time limit itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you have used a name of a command as the batch file name - try renaming it to `testftp.bat` to check that `edit:` I noticed your batch file name, but there really is nothing relaunching it that I can see; I don't know what php.exe is doing however.

Do you have a `winscp.bat` in `c:\` ?

If those are not the problem then this line will wait until the FTP has completed before continuing:

```
start "" /w /b C:\winscp.com /script=ftpScript%1.txt > ftp_result.txt
```

Comment: Hello foxidrive, none of the commands reflect the name of the batch script. I've also removed the portion where it writes the results to ftp_result. There is also no winscp.bat file in my C directory. 

PHP.exe is simply running a PHP script that sends an email to whomever recorded a video file with a link to their video file.

I will attempt to use the revision you suggested for the WINSCP line, however the script DOES wait until the transfer has completed before continuing, however during the upload it creates an additional instance of the entire batch script.

Comment: You have changed the script, as you said above, and as I outlined: there is nothing rerunning the script in what you have shown us.

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is caused by WINSCP itself? OR perhaps it's an issue with the server hosting the files? I was worried it was an issue with the application that triggers the batch script, however, this issue only has recently started to occur.

Note: We used to use the FTP command rather than using WINSCP, our new server did not allow this for some reason. This is why I'm lead to think that it's an issue with how the WINSCP line is formatted. Even then, trigger the entire batch file seems odd to me.

Comment: The reason is in the actual code. Showing us sanitised code means any answer you get is restricted to the code that you give us.

Comment: I'm attempting to understand what you mean. You said that there is nothing re-running the script in the code I've provided, so does that mean you believe the issue is within the program triggering the batch script? Thank you for taking the time to help me understand.